# md input container throwing error when I put input tags as child

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input

Trying to use the following code from the Angular examples page:

```
 <md-input-container>
    <label>Vegetables</label>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedVegetables"
               md-on-close="clearSearchTerm()"
               data-md-container-class="selectdemoSelectHeader"
               multiple>
      <md-select-header class="demo-select-header">
        <input ng-model="searchTerm"
               type="search"
               placeholder="Search for a vegetable.."
               class="demo-header-searchbox md-text">
      </md-select-header>
      <md-optgroup label="vegetables">
        <md-option ng-value="vegetable" ng-repeat="vegetable in vegetables |
          filter:searchTerm">{{vegetable}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

But this is the error I get:

Error: can only have one child input, textarea or select element!

The example can be found here (look for Select Header): https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select

Comment: did you check your version of angular material?

Comment: Are you using the same javascript as the example as well?

Comment: Both good points. Turns out it was my version of angular material. Thank you all. @Paulo Galdo Sandoval, feel free to post your reply as an answer and I will accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as i said on the comments the problem was the version of your Angular-material

Try to update it to the lastest version `1.0.9` or `1.1.0` and make a try.

```
<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js">
```

Comment: Well, this didn't worked for me. And what role the version has to play in this.

Comment: In that case was an error version because there was a bug [issue on github](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9091)

Maybe you can check if there are some other similar bug in another version

Comment: hello @paulo,

Well, i got the solution and fixed my issue.
So, the issue was, we can not use multiple input field inside <md-input-container> What you can do is to use nested <md-input-container>
which is the basic concept of <md-input-container>.

That will solve your issue. irrespective of the version you are using.

fyi: i tried v1.1.0 , 1.0.9 , 1.1.0 but issue was persisting.